# Не работает программа на Qt(Python)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Пишу конвертер величин. Написал дизайн в одном файле, подключил его к `main.py` файлу. Пробую написать пробный тест, чтобы работал вывод на `lcdnumber`. Код ошибок не выдает, но ничего и не выводит

Вот сам код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

from design import Ui_Dialog
import sys


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def time(self):
        self.lineEdit_2.text() + self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.lcd.display(int(self.lineEdit_2.text()) + int(self.lineEdit_3.text()))





app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Дизайн большой, поэтому он здесь - https://pastebin.com/BQiWvxFF

Comment: Вы забыли показать `design.py`

Comment: Отредактировал, design.py прикрепил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

#from design import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(464, 578)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 461, 241))
        self.tabWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 131, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 111, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 40, 131, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 10, 151, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 150, 141, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 71, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 141, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 90, 71, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 70, 151, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.tab)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 130, 171, 61))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 101, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 161, 22))
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 20, 101, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.comboBox_4 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_2)
        self.comboBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 50, 161, 22))
        self.comboBox_4.setObjectName("comboBox_4")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_4.addItem("")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 101, 16))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 71, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 80, 151, 16))
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 100, 71, 21))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 150, 171, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lcdNumber_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.tab_2)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 101, 61))
        self.lcdNumber_2.setObjectName("lcdNumber_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tabWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 300, 461, 261))
        self.tabWidget_2.setObjectName("tabWidget_2")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 121, 16))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.comboBox_5 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 161, 22))
        self.comboBox_5.setObjectName("comboBox_5")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_5.addItem("")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 30, 101, 16))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.comboBox_6 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_3)
        self.comboBox_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 50, 161, 22))
        self.comboBox_6.setObjectName("comboBox_6")
        self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_6.addItem("")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 101, 16))
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 90, 141, 16))
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 170, 171, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.lcdNumber_3 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.tab_3)
        self.lcdNumber_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 150, 101, 61))
        self.lcdNumber_3.setObjectName("lcdNumber_3")
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 101, 16))
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 101, 16))
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.comboBox_7 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_4)
        self.comboBox_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox_7.setObjectName("comboBox_7")
        self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_7.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_8 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.tab_4)
        self.comboBox_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 70, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox_8.setObjectName("comboBox_8")
        self.comboBox_8.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_8.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_8.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_8.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_8.addItem("")
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 101, 16))
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_4)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 100, 141, 16))
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 81, 21))
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEdit_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 120, 81, 21))
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_4)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 170, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.lcdNumber_4 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.tab_4)
        self.lcdNumber_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 150, 121, 51))
        self.lcdNumber_4.setObjectName("lcdNumber_4")
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_17.setFont(font)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
 
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidget_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Век"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Год"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Неделя"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Сутки"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "Час"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Dialog", "Минута"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Dialog", "Секунда"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Dialog", "Милисекунда"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать из"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Век"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Год"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Неделя"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Сутки"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "Час"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("Dialog", "Минута"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(6, _translate("Dialog", "Секунда"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(7, _translate("Dialog", "Милисекунда"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать в"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать --->"))          ###
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите значение"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите второе значение"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Dialog", "Конвертер времени"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать из"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Градус Цельсия (°C)"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Градус Фаренгейта (°F)"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Кельвин (K)"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Градус Реомюра (°Re)"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать в"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Градус Цельсия (°C)"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Градус Фаренгейта (°F)"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Кельвин (K)"))
        self.comboBox_4.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Градус Реомюра (°Re)"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите значение"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите второе значение"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать --->"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Dialog", "Конвертер температур"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать из"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Километр в час (км/ч)"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Метр в час (м/ч)"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Километр в секунду (км/с)"))
        self.comboBox_5.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Метр в секунду (м/с)"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать в"))
        self.comboBox_6.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Километр в час (км/ч)"))
        self.comboBox_6.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Метр в час (м/ч)"))
        self.comboBox_6.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Километр в секунду (км/с)"))
        self.comboBox_6.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Метр в секунду (м/с)"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите значение"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите второе значение"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать --->"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Dialog", "Конвертер скорости"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать из"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать в"))
        self.comboBox_7.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Километр (км)"))
        self.comboBox_7.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Метр (м)"))
        self.comboBox_7.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Дециметр (дм)"))
        self.comboBox_7.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Сантиметр (см)"))
        self.comboBox_7.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "Миллиметр (мм)"))
        self.comboBox_8.setItemText(0, _translate("Dialog", "Километр (км)"))
        self.comboBox_8.setItemText(1, _translate("Dialog", "Метр (м)"))
        self.comboBox_8.setItemText(2, _translate("Dialog", "Дециметр (дм)"))
        self.comboBox_8.setItemText(3, _translate("Dialog", "Сантиметр (см)"))
        self.comboBox_8.setItemText(4, _translate("Dialog", "Миллиметр (мм)"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите значение"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите второе значение"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Конвертировать --->"))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Dialog", "Конвертер длины"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("Dialog", "КОНВЕРТЕР"))
        

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):                                        # Ui_Dialog
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
#        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._time)                                       # +++
        
    def _time(self):
        self.lineEdit_2.text() + self.lineEdit_3.text()
#        self.lcd.display(int(self.lineEdit_2.text()) + int(self.lineEdit_3.text()))
        self.lcdNumber.display(int(self.lineEdit_2.text()) + int(self.lineEdit_3.text()))  # lcdNumber




app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, у меня все заработало. А что вы именно изменили, чтобы я знал на будущее

Comment: @любительпива я же вам отметил строки, которые изменил. См. `#`. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Все сделал, что изменилось прочитал. Вопрос пометил как верное решение. Спасибо вам еще раз, вы очень мне помогли

Comment: @любительпива пожалуйста